# I want to return a class out of 2 classes by checking the height of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

HTML code

```
<template name="temp">
<ul style="list-style-type:none" class="pcl">
    {{#each Contents}}
        {{>item}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>

<template name="item">
        <p class="bucket">
        <li class= "{{selectedClass}}">{{{content}}}</li>
        </p>
</template>
```

The template "item" is in a template "temp" which is going to run through all "item" templates. So the problem is there are going to be more than 1 {{{content}}} in a single page. So. I believe that conventional usage of "ids" and "classes" wont be useful here.
I want to check the height of the element {{{content}}} and then return a class based on it. The two classes are given in the CSS codes(contentMain and Big)

CSS codes

```
.contentMain{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    top: -15px;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype, Georgia, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.Big{
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    top: -15px;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype, Georgia, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

JS code

```
Template.item.helpers({
    'selectedClass':function(){
//codes here- if height of content is greater than 60px, then return class=.contentMain else class=.Big
      }
  });
```

Can anyone help in the codes that would come in the JS category for returning a class based on the height of the {{{content}}} elements which are going to more than 1 in a single page.
Apologies for diverting from any programming conventions or any other mistakes.(I am new to programming)

Comment: what's inside content? Can you be certain that it will have a height of its own? How and where is that defined?

Comment: {{{content}}} would contain string. Now I understand the problem with my code. How do I define the height of the {{{content}}} element. So that if the class="Big" with all its properties applied to {{{content}}} has a height less than 60px then class="Big" should be returned or else ".contentMain"should be returned. Please help! It would be very helpful.

Comment: you have an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You'll need to tell us what you are trying to accomplish first, not the solution you have in mind.

Comment: if the height of the element {{{content}}} with all the characteristics of class="Big" applied is less than 60px, then class="Big" should be returned from the helper function or else if the height is greater than 60px, then class="contentMain" should be returned.